# Remove 8.1 package from store while keeping 8.0 package

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I recently targeted Windows 8.1 while applying a new update from Visual Studio 13. I made it available in the store but now I am getting reviews that it's not working with 2 finger touch sensitivity.

I tried to understand the code but it didn't help.

Now I want to remove my Windows 8.1 targeted app from store while keeping the Windows 8 app available in place of the 8.1 app.

How and what can I do to remove that package from the Windows Dashboard (Dev center)?